# How do I update my access permission to view other profile data without getting a new api key,just by updating my existing one?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I have made a 2.0 authentication with linkedin api with the folloewing access permissions

Default Application Permissions
r_basicprofile  r_emailaddress  rw_company_admin
w_share

But when I try to make a request to search for a profile using their ID I am getting an error you don't have enough access permission.Is there a way to add access permission to this existing account.